# each and not statement do not work properly with linkyfy.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a linkyfying script on a site, which creates links out of URL's written in text. I am using this solution: https://github.com/SoapBox/linkifyjs

This is what is needed to run it (after download):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="linkify.min.js"></script>
<script src="linkify-jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery('#container').linkify();
```

This works great, but I have ran into one problem. On the site I have to use `<style>@import("[URL]")</style>` within the container sometimes. I know this is not semantically right to do (It should be within the head tag), but it is what it is and it is the only way in our system in some cases.

The problem is that linkyfy creates a link out of the import src URL if it is within the given element, in this case "#container". So then linkyfy.js do this to the @import:

```
@import url("<a href="[URL]")" class="linkified" target="_blank">[URL]")</a>;
```

Which breaks the @import totally.

So I tried to fix this. I added this:

```
jQuery('#container *').not( jQuery('style') ).each(function(){
    jQuery(this).linkify();
    //TESTING
    //jQuery(this).addClass('i-am-not-a-style-element');
});
```

**Here comes the weird(?) problem:** 
It does still linkyfies the import src URL. But If I uncomment `jQuery(this).addClass('i-am-not-a-style-element');` every element gets the class "i-am-not-a-style-element", except the `<style>` element. So it seems that my script works, but not when it comes to running the function.

I do not get why the function `linkyfy();`still run on the `not()` element above.

Would be grateful for help!

Comment: Does it validate and work in IE9?

Comment: I meant `<link rel="stylesheet" href="[URL]">`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes care of my problem. It is not the exact the answer to my question. But it is a workaround which I started to investigate after the answer from @Jasny - Arnold Daniels. This do not validate inside `body` (Just to show):

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />`

But this validates in HTML5 (With `property="stylesheet"`) inside `body`, and it works in IE9:

`<link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="test.css">`

And by doing this, `linkify()` leaves the URL alone since it is inside anchors.